# Graph Implementation in Java 8

Tags: java, graph

Here is my code which implements a simple directed graph in Java 8. Here are some of the things I am unsure about:

1. I am fairly new to Java 8 concepts. Have I used the new API correctly (and not increased the running time of the operations)?
2. In the current implementation, there is no way to iterate over the list of the edges. Is this a shortcoming?
3. Right now, adding new operations like DFS or weighted shortest path, I will have to change the `Graph.java` class. How can I improve the design such that adding graph algorithms, does not require changing the graph data class (or is there no need to do this)?

**Graph.java**

```
public class Graph<T> {

    private Map<T, Node<T>> adjacencyList;

    public Graph() {
        adjacencyList = new HashMap<>();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a vertex to the graph.
     * @param vertex        vertex to add
     */
    public boolean addVertex(T vertex) {
        if (adjacencyList.containsKey(vertex)) {
            return false;
        }
        adjacencyList.put(vertex, new Node<>(vertex));
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a directed edge between two vertices in the graph.
     * @param vertex1       vertex where the (directed) edge begins
     * @param vertex2       vertex where the (directed) edge ends
     */
    public boolean addEdge(T vertex1, T vertex2) {
        return addEdge(vertex1, vertex2, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a weighted directed edge between two vertices in the graph.
     * @param vertex1       vertex where the (directed) edge begins
     * @param vertex2       vertex where the (directed) edge ends
     * @param weight        weight of the edge
     */
    public boolean addEdge(T vertex1, T vertex2, int weight) {
        if (!containsVertex(vertex1) || !containsVertex(vertex2)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Vertex does not exist");
        }

        // add the edge
        Node<T> node1 = getNode(vertex1);
        Node<T> node2 = getNode(vertex2);
        return node1.addEdge(node2, weight);
    }

    /**
     * Remove a vertex from the graph.
     * @param vertex        vertex to be removed
     * @return      true if the vertex was removed, false if no such vertex was found.
     */
    public boolean removeVertex(T vertex) {
        if (!adjacencyList.containsKey(vertex)) {
            return false;
        }

        // get node to be removed
        final Node<T> toRemove = getNode(vertex);

        // remove all incoming edges to node
        adjacencyList.values().forEach(node -> node.removeEdge(toRemove));

        // remove the node
        adjacencyList.remove(vertex);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Method to remove a directed edge between two vertices in the graph.
     * @param vertex1       vertex where the (directed) edge begins
     * @param vertex2       vertex where the (directed) edge ends
     * @return  true if the edge was removed, false if no such edge was found.
     */
    public boolean removeEdge(T vertex1, T vertex2) {
        if (!containsVertex(vertex1) || !containsVertex(vertex2)) {
            return false;
        }
        return getNode(vertex1).removeEdge(getNode(vertex2));
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the number of vertices in the graph.
     * @return      count of vertices
     */
    public int vertexCount() {
        return adjacencyList.keySet().size();
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the number of edges in the graph.
     * @return      count of edges
     */
    public int edgeCount() {
        return adjacencyList.values()
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(Node::getEdgeCount)
                .sum();
    }

    /**
     * Method to check if a vertex exists in the graph.
     * @param vertex    vertex which is to be checked
     * @return  returns true if the graph contains the vertex, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean containsVertex(T vertex) {
        return adjacencyList.containsKey(vertex);
    }

    /**
     * Method to check if an edge exists in the graph.
     * @param vertex1       vertex where the (directed) edge begins
     * @param vertex2       vertex where the (directed) edge ends
     * @return   returns true if the graph contains the edge, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean containsEdge(T vertex1, T vertex2) {
        if (!containsVertex(vertex1) || !containsVertex(vertex2)) {
            return false;
        }
        return getNode(vertex1).hasEdge(getNode(vertex2));
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the shortest path from startVertex to endVertex.
     * @param startVertex   vertex where the path begins
     * @param endVertex     vertex where the path ends
     * @return  list of vertices in the shortest path from startVertex to endVertex,
     *          null if no such path exists.
     */
    @Nullable
    public List<T> shortestPath(T startVertex, T endVertex) {
        // if nodes not found, return empty path
        if (!containsVertex(startVertex) || !containsVertex(endVertex)) {
            return null;
        }
        // run bfs on the graph
        runBFS(startVertex);

        List<T> path = new ArrayList<>();
        // trace path back from end vertex to start
        Node<T> end = getNode(endVertex);
        while (end != null && end != getNode(startVertex)) {
            path.add(end.vertex());
            end = end.parent();
        }
        // if end is null, node not found
        if (end == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            Collections.reverse(path);
        }
        return path;
    }

    private void runBFS(T startVertex) {
        if (!containsVertex(startVertex)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Vertex does not exist.");
        }

        // reset the graph
        resetGraph();

        // init the queue
        Queue<Node<T>> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        Node<T> start = getNode(startVertex);
        queue.add(start);

        // explore the graph
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node<T> first = queue.remove();
            first.setVisited(true);
            first.edges().forEach(edge -> {
                Node<T> neighbour = edge.toNode();
                if (!neighbour.isVisited()) {
                    neighbour.setParent(first);
                    queue.add(neighbour);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private Node<T> getNode(T value) {
        return adjacencyList.get(value);
    }

    private void resetGraph() {
        adjacencyList.keySet().forEach(key -> {
            Node<T> node = getNode(key);
            node.setParent(null);
            node.setVisited(false);
        });
    }
}
```

**Node.java**

```
public class Node<T> {

    private T vertex;

    private List<Edge<T>> edges;

    private Node<T> parent;

    private boolean isVisited;

    public Node(T vertex) {
        this.vertex = vertex;
        this.edges = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public T vertex() {
        return vertex;
    }

    public boolean addEdge(Node<T> node, int weight) {
        if (hasEdge(node)) {
            return false;
        }
        Edge<T> newEdge = new Edge<>(this, node, weight);
        return edges.add(newEdge);
    }

    public boolean removeEdge(Node<T> node) {
        Optional<Edge<T>> optional = findEdge(node);
        if (optional.isPresent()) {
            return edges.remove(optional.get());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hasEdge(Node<T> node) {
        return findEdge(node).isPresent();
    }

    private Optional<Edge<T>> findEdge(Node<T> node) {
        return edges.stream()
                .filter(edge -> edge.isBetween(this, node))
                .findFirst();
    }

    public List<Edge<T>> edges() {
        return edges;
    }

    public int getEdgeCount() {
        return edges.size();
    }

    public Node<T> parent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return isVisited;
    }

    public void setVisited(boolean isVisited) {
        this.isVisited = isVisited;
    }

    public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

**Edge.java**

```
public class Edge<T> {

    private Node<T> node1;

    private Node<T> node2;

    private int weight;

    public Edge(Node<T> node1, Node<T> node2, int weight) {
        this.node1 = node1;
        this.node2 = node2;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Node<T> fromNode() {
        return node1;
    }

    public Node<T> toNode() {
        return node2;
    }

    public boolean isBetween(Node<T> node1, Node<T> node2) {
        return (this.node1 == node1 && this.node2 == node2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

These are mostly going to be general comments.

---

```
private Map<T, Node<T>> adjacencyList;
```

This field can (and should) be made `final`. This applies to fields in your other classes as well.

I also don't see why you initialize it in the constructor. You can just initialize it at declaration and drop the constructor entirely, since it will then be the default constructor.

I also find it slightly confusing that the name suggests that it is a list when really it is a `Map`. This is a mismatch.

---

```
public boolean addVertex(T vertex) {
    if (adjacencyList.containsKey(vertex)) {
        return false;
    }
    adjacencyList.put(vertex, new Node<>(vertex));
    return true;
}
```

You have a method `containsVertex` that you also use in your other methods. You should use it here as well. This also applies to other places in your code.

---

```
if (!containsVertex(vertex1) || !containsVertex(vertex2)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Vertex does not exist");
}
```

You could use a custom exception here, e.g., `VertexNotFoundException` or something similar. This makes exception handling easier for the caller.

Also, this kind of code is duplicated. You could create a private `checkVertexExists` method (or some other name) to which you pass a vertex and that immediately throws if the vertex doesn't exist.

---

```
// add the edge
// get node to be removed
// remove all incoming edges to node
// remove the node
```

These are all noise comments and are meaningless. Don't comment the obvious. Let your code comment itself. There are more comments of this kind, this is just a small selection.

---

```
// run bfs on the graph
runBFS(startVertex);
```

Again, this comment is meaningless. But also, `runBFS` is a relatively cryptic method name. What if I don't know that acronym? I would use a more descriptive name here.

---

```
if (end == null) {
    return null;
}
else {
    Collections.reverse(path);
}
return path;
```

You don't need that `else` block at all since the `if` case immediately returns. Just put the `reverse` call prior to the `return path` and drop the `else`.

---

```
private void runBFS(T startVertex) {
    // ...
}
```

Apart from renaming it, which I mentioned above, this method is too long and does too much. Split it up into parts. In fact, you may find that it might be worth extracting this into another class entirely.

Comment: thanks for the tips and comments. I am actually more troubled by points 1, 2, and 3 (which are design related) than the minor issues with the code itself.